# Creating a new table from two existing tables with every combination possibility

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two temporary tables #a and #b both filled with integer values. Let's say they both contain 10 rows with values 1-10.

I want to create a third temporary table #c that contains every possible combination of a and b. So it would have 100 rows total with (1,1), (1,2) ... (10, 10). How would I go about doing this in SQL. The implementation I'm using is SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you can just do

```
SELECT * INTO #c FROM #a,#b
```

Answer (score 8):

Cross join will get all combinations

```
SELECT a.Col
, b.Col
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN TableB b
```

Comment: The syntax `SELECT * FROM TABLE1,TABLE2` will `CROSS JOIN` if no join condition is specified.

Comment: CROSS JOIN is much preferable syntax to the comma.

Comment: +1 for using `CROSS JOIN` to state your intention. `from #a,#b` could just be sloppy programmer

Comment: I would at least rename one column. SQLFiddle doesn't even show the 2nd

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @a TABLE(x INT)
DECLARE @b TABLE(x INT)
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (1), (2)
INSERT INTO @b VALUES (1), (2)
select * from @a,@b
END
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly other correct answers here but I'll add the best elements of them together to answer the question completely:

```
select a.Col as ColA    -- Give the columns a name for the destination
    , b.Col as ColB
into #c                 -- Generates destination temp table #c
from #a as a
    cross join #b as b  -- Cross join is the preferred syntax
order by a.Col, b.Col   -- Optional but often helpful (aesthetic, identities, indexing, etc)
```

So yes, when you want a cartesian product, use a [cross join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx).