# Merging multiple sql table results into one

Tags: mysql

I have imported several large `csv`'s and I am looking to create a merged table from several imports.

So lets say I have 2 tables.

`table1`:

```
title
ben
rupert
```

`table2`:

```
title
karen
jill
```

and I want to either populate an empty table or create one on the fly.

//NewTable

```
title
ben
rupert
karen
jill
```

I've tried using `SQL` like this - but I am getting `NewTable` undefined variable issues

```
select * 
into `NewTable`
from(
    select * from `table1`
    union all
    select * from `table2`
    union all
)t
```

Comment: create NewTable first

Comment: --I've made it - same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056702/3164682

Comment: [SQL]select * 
into `NewTable`
from(
    select * from `table1`
    union all
    select * from `table2`
)t

[Err] 1327 - Undeclared variable: NewTable

Comment: use INSERT INTO NewTable (columns) select columns from () t

Comment: SELECT * INTO `NewTable` FROM `table1`,`table2`  -- same error -

Comment: change the syntax and use the above one

Comment: "INSERT INTO `NewTable`
from(
    select * from `table1`
    union all
    select * from `table2`
    union all
)t"  -- error   [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from(
    select * from `table1`
    union all
    select * from `table2`
  ' at line 2

Comment: @Sarah that would create all combinations of rows out of those tables, but OP wants them appended. So `UNION` is probably what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `NewTable` first then:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

An alternate way in which you wouldn't need to create the table first, off the top of my head would be:

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM table1
```

And then perform the insert from the second table:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select ... into ...` statement in MySQL is for populating variables. What you are looking for is the `insert ... select ...` [statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
insert into newtable
select * from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table1 select * from table2;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (merging 2 tables into a new one). Your code is just copying one table into another.